# How to color-code plotted points in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a simple `data.frame` as follows:

```
    status   age   score
    0        34    90
    0        56    70
    1        44    69 
    0        53    88
    1        54    44
```

Then I plotted score against age

```
   plot(age, score)
```

My question is how do I color code the points respective to their status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory `ggplot` solution:

```
gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=age, y=score, color=factor(status)))
gg <- gg + geom_point(size=3)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
DF <- data.frame(
  status=c(0,0,1,0,1),
  age=c(34,56,44,53,54),
  score=c(90,70,69,88,44)
)
##
with(DF, plot(age,score,col=(1+status)))
```

You need to add `1` to the status vector (or any other constant > 0) because plotting with `col=0` will not produce a point.
[image]

Or to add labels,

```
with(
  DF,
  plot(
    x=age,y=score,pch=20,
    col=(1+status)
  )
)
legend(
  "top",
  legend=paste0(
    "Status: ",
    unique(DF$status)
  ),
  pch=20,
  col=(1+unique(DF$status)),
  bty="n",
  horiz=TRUE
)
```

[image]

Comment: Also, this only works because `status` is a `numeric` vector and `col` accepts `numeric` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of base plotting.  I would just create a color vector using an ifelse() and then feed that to plot().

This method allows you maximum customizeability with color mapping.

```
status <- c(0,0,1,0,1)
colvec <- ifelse( status == 1, "red", "blue")
age <- c(seq(1,length.out=5, by=1))
score <- c(90, 70, 69, 88, 44)

plot(age, score, col=colvec, pch=19)
```